# Function for calculating number of votes in Cloude Code on Parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am just starting with parse Cloude Code, so I am not good with it.

I have custom VoteObject with following field:

- vote As String

Vote is string from 1 to N.
I have iOS app and every time when I vote in it, I send vote number to parse.
Like first vote is number 1, second number 2, and so on.

Now I wont to make custom Cloude Code that will return number of votes for every vote.
I come to https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions and this is what I have so far:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("stat", function(request, response) {
  var query = new Parse.Query("VoteObject");
  query.find({
    success: function(results) {
      var sum = 0;
      // make dictionary in JavaScript

      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {
        sum += results[i].get("vote");

        // if vote key does not exist in dictionary, put it to 1
        // if exist, +1
      }

      // return dictionary 
      response.success(sum / results.length);
    },
    error: function() {
      response.error("NO STAT");
    }
  });
});
```

I know what algorithm to implement (I have write it as comment), but do not know how to do it on Parse.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by the "number of votes for every vote"? From the way you described it there will be one record with "1", one with "2" etc... is there some other field that describes what is being voted on or something?

Comment: each record represent one vote, if i have record like this 1,2,3,2,2,1,1,1,2,2. Result should be {"1": 4, "2": 5, "3": 1}

Comment: OK, please add that information to your question, I'll start working on an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can go about this:

1. Iterate through every record increasing counters as you go
2. Chain together some `count()` queries

Option 1 has some issues with scaling (especially at the 1,000 record mark, and even more critically at the 10,000 mark).

Option 2 requires you to know what the maximum vote can be, but that shouldn't be a problem I hope.

Here's a sample for #2:

```
var queries = [];
var totals = {};
// change this as needed
var maxVote = 3;

for (var vote = 1; vote <= maxVote; vote++) {
  totals[vote.toString()] = 0;
  var query = new Parse.Query("VoteObject");
  var query.equalTo('vote', vote.toString());

  // push into parallel promises array
  queries.push(query.count().then(function(count) {
    var localVote = vote.toString();
    totals[localVote] = count;
  });
}

// wait for them all to finish, order isn't important
Parse.Promise.when(queries).then(function() {
  // all totals calculated, do something with totals object
});
```

That should work if I haven't made any mistakes.